# Assessing water damage to wood beneath bathroom

Tags: bathroom, wood, damage

Some tiles are coming up from our bathroom floor. I haven’t yet taken off the thinset mortar to assess if there’s any damage but I went beneath the house and found a good bit of wet wood. How bad does this look from first glance?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a lot worse. There doesn't appear to be any mold. I'd rip the thinset up to the extent of the loose tiles and the water staining below as soon as possible and start the drying out process. When the drying is complete, you'll be in a better position to judge for damage. If you caught it fast, you'll probably be OK. Once dried, you might think about spraying some white vinegar on the wood to kill any mold/mildew that might be thinking about growing.

Comment: Looks like there's a bit of green around the edges of the moisture on the joists and subfloor. Looks a bit like mold to me, but not the scary black stuff and nothing to worry about. There's no signs of rot, at least from below, so it looks good structurally.

Comment: Thanks all - I upvoted but it won’t show as I don’t have enough rep yet - just bought a house, so that will likely change soon. :) I chiseled out the thinset and am going to monitor the moisture/rent something to apply heat and dry the wood. Appreciate the feedback.